# I use Chrome as my default browser on Mac, but use Safari exclusively on iPhone - How can I keep bookmarks in sync?

Tags: iphone, icloud, safari, google-chrome, bookmarks

So as per the title, I use Chrome on my mac but Safari on my iOS devices.

I'm struggling to find a way to sync the bookmarks I add on my Mac computer to Safari as a whole, previously it seemed as though Xmarks was a good solution, but it's defunct.

It's frustrating as this is possible on the PC, but not on a Mac where I do the majority of my computing, and the stupid chrome bookmark sync won't run on a mac saying it's designed to run on a PC, but yet there it's handled by iCloud.

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: How do you sync Safari & Chrome bookmarks on your Windows machine?

Comment: Well I sort of both solved the problem and made it infinitely worse. On windows you can set up iCloud syncing of bookmarks from all browsers I figured that would be a solution for the time being as I don’t add a ton of bookmarks. And to be fair, it worked. It also wiped out my entire bookmarks saved on my phone/mac/etc. All gone. The only saving grace is that I had set up time machine on my Mac recently and could get a backup. So make sure you back your bookmarks up before trying. Apple STILL hasn’t fixed this stupidity.